# Send hot key to program while windows is locked

Tags: windows, winapi, gina

Is it possible to send hot key to program while windows is locked? Maybe i should modify gina.dll?

Answer (score 0):

I would think if thats posible that would be a design flaw :)

Might be posible wish some driver, that again passes the hotkey to your spesfic program.

Comment: If i'll get driver for keyboard from WDK and modify for my needs, will it work?